# Can I disable a global type declaration?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, gsap

I would happily take edits on this title.

I am using `npm install gsap` and it comes with Types which is great!  But I believe part of those types is a `gsap` global.

This means that at author time,  I can use `gsap` and I get no errors,  my build is a success,  but I forgot to `import { gsap } from "gsap"` into the files that actually use it. So it fails at runtime only if you hit that non-imported code.  VSCode thinks a global is there available to my project, but there isn't one in reality, and so even auto imports are skipped.

**Is there a way to somehow disable global module declarations either on a per library basis or entirely? I want to use the types, but the ambient declation(?) included with them is hurting.**

Sample:

```
// no imports
export class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        gsap.to(this, { y: 100 });
      //^^^^ gsap isn't imported,  this should be throwing an error
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is standard practice. I don't think it's possible to disable this behavior.